# What is the minimum thickness of an insulated bathroom wall

Tags: bathroom, insulation, framing

I am trying to build a basement bathroom in the corner of the house.  Where I am, basement insulation codes are R10/13.   What is the minimum that I can do to frame and insulate a wall.  The two methods that I thought of were 2" XPS (to get R10) + 2x3 furring strip + 0.5" cement board. That's 5".  Maybe I could do 0.5" XPS for vapor barrier, then a 2x4 wall with batt insulation in the voids.  That's 4.5".  Is there anything wrong with that and/or is there a better way?

Comment: Both bathroom and basement imply moisture. While batt insulation will be fine if properly installed, I'd favor a solid insulation because it is less likely to serve as a substrate for mold should there be a problem with the installation or down the road with maintenance. Given the limited amount of wall involved, it's more likely to be worth the additional cost.

Comment: The problem isn't the cost, the problem is the limited space.  I'm trying to fit in a shower, toilet and sink and I'm running out of space.

Comment: 3/4" Hat Channel furring on insulated wall. 1 1/2" Light Gauge metal studs for interior partitions without plumbing stack. Saves meaningful space.